# BJT transistors with circuittikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am unable to modify the circuit tikz to look like the one from the picture [image]

1. The voltage sources are inversed
2. I don’t know how to add the V1 and V2 externally
3. The resistor is missing

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
  (0,0) node[pnp] (pnp1){$Q_2$} ++(.7,0) % add white space for label   
   (pnp1.B) -- ++(-.5,0) node[pnp, xscale=-1, anchor=B](pnp2){}  
  (pnp2.text) node[above left,inner sep=0pt] {$Q_1$}       
   (pnp1.B) |- (pnp1.C)
   (pnp2.B) |- (pnp2.C)
   (pnp1.text) node[below right,inner sep=10pt] {$N$} 
   (pnp2.text) node[below left,inner sep=10pt] {$1$} 

%     (npn1.E) -- ++(0,2) node[R, l_=$R_1$,-*]

      (pnp2.E) to [american, I , l_=$I_o$,-] ++(0,2) coordinate(a)
      (pnp1.E) to [american, I , l_=$I_o$,-] ++(0,2) coordinate(b)
     (a)-- (b) node[vcc]{$V_{cc}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `invert` to invert the current sources. For drawing resistor you have to use `(npn1.E) to[R] ++(0,2)`.

Comment: where should I add this invert?

Comment: `to[american,I, invert]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `invert` to change the current or voltage source direction.

   2. V1 and V2 can be placed at required coordinates using `node`.
   3. Like any bipole, resistor can be placed with `to[R]`

See MWE.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt]
\draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[Tpnp,name=Q1] ++(0,2) to[short] ++(0,2)node(v1){} to[I,invert,l^=$i_0$] ++(0,2)node[tground]{};
\draw (3,0) node[ground]{} to[Tpnp,mirror,name=Q2] ++(0,2) to[R,a=$R$] ++(0,2)node(v2){} to[I,invert,l_=$i_0$] ++(0,2)node[tground]{};
\draw (Q1.B) |- (0,0);
\draw (Q2.B) |- (3,0);
\draw (v1) to[short] ++(1,0)node[below]{$v_1$} to[open,o-o] ++(1,0)node[below]{$v_2$} to[short] (v2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, off-topic: on the top I would not  use ground symbol (well, this is also wrong in OP sketch) for supply voltage (usually designated as `$V_{cc}$`) :-) . Nice answer, +1.